# Workflow for editing a 2D tiled level with some layers that are whole images?

Tags: level-design, terminology, levels, asset-workflow

**Context**
I'm making a *2.5D game* from scratch using *C/C++*.

**Issue/question:**
I specifically want a way to edit my levels that lets me enter an *image for each layer of the level*, like *hoodcraft.py* in *POSTAL*.

Would what I'm looking for be a level editor where the floor, buildings, vfx, etc. are just images layered on top of each other while still having tilemaps for players, AI and other interactable objects?

I need some help setting up a workflow to produce such levels — are there existing tools I can use to do this (and if so, how do I do this in those tools), or standard terminology that will help me find suitable tools/techniques?

Comment: Even the good old rpg maker can export maps (tile map editor with multiple layers). For 2.5d just search for a tile editor, your favorite search engine will show a lot of results for that